# How to access and style singel html-tag within html.twig

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

i am trying to use bootstrap within html.twig-file.
Situation:
i have this code line within html.twig:

```
{{ form_row(form.gender) }}
```

Here is a definition of "form.gender" within php

```
 ->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'form.register.children.gender.choice.male' => 'm',
                    'form.register.children.gender.choice.female' => 'f'
                ),
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ))
```

From this code-line will be generated big html-area:

```html
<div>
  <label class="required">Gender:</label>
  <div id="new_entry_gender">
    <input id="new_entry_gender_0"                
           name="catalog_new_entry[gender][]"      
           value="m" 
           type="checkbox">
    <label for="catalog_new_entry_gender_0">Male</label>


    <input id="new_entry_gender_1" 
           name="catalog_new_entry[gender][]"     
           value="f" 
           type="checkbox">
    <label for="catalog_new_entry_gender_1">Female</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like use bootstrap-classes for any singel html-tag like: label, input
But i have only one line:

```
{{ form_row(form.gender) }}
```

How can i access to any singel html-tag (for styling), when i have only one line above?
Thx
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the html code is autogenerated, try defining css for the class/id name which gets automatically generated.

Define the autogenerated classname/id css by copying the css from bootstrap, corresponding to css for that particular html element.

eg: define the css for id (**new_entry_gender**) of your autogenerated **div element**

by copying the properties of  class name **form-group** in boostrap.

This may work.

Or alternatively you can use jQuery 
Write your script as

- Select that autogenerated item by id
- Add the boostrap class name to the item, using .addClass() in Jquery

Comment: thanks :)

for example i´am using classes from bootstrap like this:

`<label class="label label-pill label-default" for="catalog_new_entry_entryText">Entry</label>
    `

so i create own css-file, which i include into my html. Within own css-file i include bootstrap-classes:

`@import url("./bootstrap.css");

label{
 label;
 label-pill;
 label-default
} `

but it does not work.
I want to set by some id´s, classes or html-tags some bootstrap-classes within own css file, which will be included into html.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, render each form [field section individually](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-rendering-basics), as example, use this:

```
<div>
    {{ form_label(form.gender) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.gender) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.gender) }}
</div>
```

Instead of

```
{{ form_row(form.gender) }}
```

Then you can simply use [Form Variables](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#using-form-variables):

```
{# render a widget, but add a "foo" class to it #}
{{ form_widget(form.gender, { 'attr': {'class': 'foo'} }) }}
```

For advanced customization of an individual Field you can take a look at the [doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field).

Hope this help

Comment: i dont know, how can i set excatly on html-tag "label" some label-bootstrape classes, when i say only:

 {{ form_row(form.entryText, { 'attr': {'class': 'label label-default label-pill'} }) }}

i have to navigate within html.twig exactly on some html-tag, which is not rendered on html.twig

Comment: Hi @RomaKap I update my answer with better explanation about the process. Let me know if now is more clear